Unfreeze both columns and rows with openpyxl
I've been trying to unfreeze the first 2 rows and first column with openpyxl, however, when opening the file using Excel, I would get a message stating that Excel found some problem with some content in the file, and if I want to recover as much as they can. When I recover the contents of the file, it appears that the pane is not frozen anymore, even though that pop-up appeared.
Current code I have to unfreeze panes:
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.views import Selection, Pane

filename = '...\\ExcelFile.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active

# current code to "unfreeze" panes
# get a pop-up error when opening file using excel
ws.views.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = 'A1'  # scroll to top left corner
ws.views.sheetView[0].pane = Pane()  # makes pane empty
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0] = Selection()
wb.save(filename)

Is there a way to not have the contents corrupted when unfreezing the panes? Would appreciate the help. Thanks.
Current data in Excel file (NOTE: working with only example data before applying to actual files):

Edit: Adding sheetview of the current sheet before "freezing" pane and sheetview of the sheet when freezing the pane is applied.
Before freezing the pane
<openpyxl.worksheet.views.SheetView object>
Parameters:
windowProtection=None, showFormulas=None, showGridLines=None, showRowColHeaders=None, showZeros=None, rightToLeft=None, tabSelected=True, showRuler=None, showOutlineSymbols=None, defaultGridColor=None, showWhiteSpace=None, view=None, topLeftCell=None, colorId=None, zoomScale=None, zoomScaleNormal=None, zoomScaleSheetLayoutView=None, zoomScalePageLayoutView=None, zoomToFit=None, workbookViewId=0, pane=None, selection=[<openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection object>
Parameters:
pane=None, activeCell='A1', activeCellId=None, sqref='A1']

Freezing is applied to sheet
<openpyxl.worksheet.views.SheetView object>
Parameters:
windowProtection=None, showFormulas=None, showGridLines=None, showRowColHeaders=None, showZeros=None, rightToLeft=None, tabSelected=True, showRuler=None, showOutlineSymbols=None, defaultGridColor=None, showWhiteSpace=None, view=None, topLeftCell=None, colorId=None, zoomScale=None, zoomScaleNormal=None, zoomScaleSheetLayoutView=None, zoomScalePageLayoutView=None, zoomToFit=None, workbookViewId=0, pane=<openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane object>
Parameters:
xSplit=1.0, ySplit=2.0, topLeftCell='B3', activePane='bottomRight', state='frozen', selection=[<openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection object>
Parameters:
pane='topRight', activeCell=None, activeCellId=None, sqref=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection object>
Parameters:
pane='bottomLeft', activeCell=None, activeCellId=None, sqref=None, <openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection object>
Parameters:
pane='bottomRight', activeCell='A1', activeCellId=None, sqref='A1']


It's openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) but otherwise code looks OK and will unfreeze a sheet as described. However from memory I think some workbooks do have issues depending on how they were created. Can you use Xlwings instead? That usually works without issue.

I think you probably want to reset the whole SheetView. What does this look like before you start changing it?

@CharlieClark The image shown is roughly what it looks like before starting to freeze cell B3, so that both the row and columns will freeze.

No, what does the SheetView look like?

@CharlieClark Sorry for the late reply, I added the sheetview of both when the sheet does not have the freeze_panes property set and when the freeze_panes property is applied.

That doesn't match your code, but it should tell you what to do.
